# Typo3 Extbase Debug shows invisible object

Tags: debugging, typo3, fluid, tx-news

I tried to extend the news extension (news system) with my own extension to add an `OR` to the SQL list request of news.

I used the `findDemandedRaw()` method which returns the SQL query of a query object. The SQL request is OK, but I don't get any results in the list page.

But it works when I insert the news object in the debug ViewHelper of Fluid `<f:debug title="Debug">{news}</f:debug>` - my news are displayed on the page!

I can't let the Debug in my page so, what's going on here?
Is there a configuration mistake?

Answer (score 0):

maybe u missed to define a page/folder for your plugin where the data is saved. go to your plugin, on the page you inserted it.  under "behavior" you have to select a page/folder where the data is saved. hope it is that simple.